# Is there an on-premise (offline) version of Here's platform?

Tags: here-api

Probably not a Stack Overflow question but I can't find this on here.com.

Is there a version of here.com platform available for on-premise installation?  We are looking for a solution that can place markers and draw lines on a map without internet access.

I understand that there are some features (geolocation, reverse location, etc) that would be unavailable in a intranet only installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is mapping, geocoding, routing and more available for on-premise.
Contact a sales rep through developer.here.com portal to get more information